# Unhandled Exception: setState() called in constructor: ReservationMakingState#861c9(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im creating an app thats making reservations for boat rentals, but i struggle to fix this problem any1 can help?
Providing code samples:

```
          if (docs.size == 0) {
            reservations.doc(resID).set({
              'resID': resID,
              'name': name,
              "surname": surname,
              "phoneNumber": phoneNumber,
              "rental": ProductCardInCart.rental,
              'boat': ProductCardInCart.boat,
              'date': date,
              'time': time
            }).then((value) {
              print("Reservation made");
              setState(() {
                Body.empty = true;
              });
            }).catchError((error) => print("Failed to reservate: $error"));
          } else if (docs.size != 0) {
            setState(() {
              Body.empty = false;
            });
            print('jestjus');
          }
        });
      } else {
        return;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

this setstate is working well

```
.then((value) {
              print("Reservation made");
              setState(() {
                Body.empty = true;
              });
```

but this one isnt and its throwing exception

```
} else if (docs.size != 0) {
            setState(() {
              Body.empty = false;
            });
            print('jestjus');
          }
```

Error that its throwing:

```
7980): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called in constructor: ReservationMakingState#861c9(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)
E/flutter ( 7980): This happens when you call setState() on a State object for a widget that hasn't been inserted into the widget tree yet. It is not necessary to call setState() in the constructor, since the state is already assumed to be dirty when it is initially created.
```

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your `setState` isn't working is because your widget is still being built. It can't update until AFTER the widget has completed its first build.

the reason that this one works

```dart
.then((value) {
   print("Reservation made");
   setState(() {
     Body.empty = true;
   });
});
```

is because it is happening after a future `.then(() {});`

if you would like to have your widget rebuild after it has initially been set up you can use
**Be careful using this. if you use it within your build method, you will get stuck in a loop! You should have this in a `initState` method or have some conditional statement before this is run**

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      //do something call your set state here
    });
  }
```

Comment: I just insert that into my method and it seems to didnt help at all

Comment: this method is reservation making logic, and if it sees that theres a reservation at this boat at this time and date already, it should show text on screen that says that its not avaible

Comment: How is your method set up? if you just copy and paste this to replace your existing code, its not going to do anything. The initState needs to be outside of your build method for this to work.